# DAX Measure no longer calculates accurately if I sort an axis by another column?

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I'm having some trouble creating a DAX Measure in PowerBI that will group sales by quarter, but still sort correctly. Our sales data is received cumulatively and once a quarter. I've created the following DAX Measure to calculate the quarterly sales:

```
Quarterly Sales = SWITCH(
SELECTEDVALUE(FactSales[Quarter]),
"Q1 2018/19",CALCULATE(sum(FactSales[Quantity]),FactSales[Quarter]="Q1 2018/19"),
"Q2 2018/19",CALCULATE(sum(FactSales[Quantity]),FactSales[Quarter]="Q2 2018/19")-CALCULATE(sum(FactSales[Quantity]),FactSales[Quarter]="Q1 2018/19"),
"Q3 2018/19",CALCULATE(sum(FactSales[Quantity]),FactSales[Quarter]="Q3 2018/19")-CALCULATE(sum(FactSales[Quantity]),FactSales[Quarter]="Q2 2018/19"),
"Q4 2019/20",CALCULATE(sum(FactSales[Quantity]),FactSales[Quarter]="Q4 2018/19")-CALCULATE(sum(FactSales[Quantity]),FactSales[Quarter]="Q3 2018/19"),
"Q1 2019/20",CALCULATE(sum(FactSales[Quantity]),FactSales[Quarter]="Q1 2019/20")
)
```

The problem is, while this calculates accurate numbers, it chart sorts this alphabetically, so the two Q1s are beside each other. when I try to sort the Quarter column by a Sorting dummy column, the calculations then all become out of wack and are no longer accurate.

I feel like there must be an easy way to fix this, but I can't figure out how to do it. Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Each sale has most likely a sales date, this you should use in your visuals. power-bi can work with the date to show your sales in any shape you want, per month, Quarter, year etc. you even can decide how you want to drill down..

Comment: This could be solved with a calendar table and and some basic time intelligence functions like parallel period. Your recreating in effect these functions

Comment: @Aldert long story short, but unfortunately my data is aggregated as I described above, and I have no way of acquiring de-aggregated data that would allow me to know sales date.